# DAX SUM with Two Filter and Ignore negative value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

```
AR Outstanding = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Invoices[Customer Invoice]),
    FILTER(
        Invoices, 
        Invoices[Invoice Status]=0
    ),
    FILTER(
        Invoices, 
        Invoices[Customer Invoice]>1
    )
)
```

1. Filter = Invoice Status 0 means “UNPAID”
2. Filter = Customer Invoice >1 Any invoice greater that $1.00 dollars, so meaning ignore any negative value.

Example: =SUMIF(A2:A89,">1") Calculation in Excel work, not in DAX.

The formula work well overall, except decimal value. Is not calculating any decimal.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your formula not only ignoring negative value but also value 1. Is that expected? what you mean by ignoring decimal values? is it ignoring 1.01 or only values less then equal 1 like .99? Please provide some sample data for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** You have filtered data with condition **>1**, which means it will filter all negative value as well as from 0.0 to 1.0. So this will also filter out some positive values like 0.12, 0.99

**Issue-2:** Another possible case can be the **data type** of your **measure**. If that is a **Whole Number**, it should give you a feeling of missing decimal values in the SUM function.

**Finally**, You can write your Measure as bellow to combine all filters together as below-

```
AR Outstanding = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Invoices[Customer Invoice]),
    FILTER(
        Invoices, 
        Invoices[Invoice Status] = 0
            && Invoices[Customer Invoice] > 1
            //-- I Guess the above condition should be **>0**
    )
)
```